# Getting "no healthy upstream" after renaming the service at eks clster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio, istio-sidecar

Created and deployed application at eks cluster. Istio configured on cluster. API was working fine. Later renamed the virtual service, then getting

`no healthy upstream.`

What would be the issue with istio-proxy ?

Comment: I  inspect the ingress gateway proxy config, its having old and new service url on it. 

istioctl proxy-config cluster -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway-xxxxxxxx.

Comment: Could you include your deployment files?